# how to add a “.so” library in a Netbeans project in Ubuntu

Tags: java, libraries, netbeans

I am a beginner in Netbeans JAVA development. I am searching for this solution for a long time and I have found some answers from here and here too but I can't make it work.

I have also tried to run this commands:

```
java -Djava.library.path=<path/to/the/libs>
```

*this gives me this output:*

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

**and**

```
java -Djava.library.path=path/to/the/libs
```

*this gives me the default help menu of java.*

please give me a detailed guide how to add .so library files in a Netbeans project in ubuntu.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Normally .so files are installed via apt as something-dev packages. But this depends on what libraries you need in your project.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I want to add the **rxtxserial** library in my projrct. The library is in **.so** format. Please tell me how to add it to my Netbeans Java Project?

Answer (score 1):

install the `librxtx-java` through the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

this should be sufficient, I think - I'm no java-developer, though.